# Why do my bottom divs appear not centered on android but does on a monitor?

Tags: html, css, web

I've looked around and can't seem to find a solution to the problem.

How come the bottom two divs appear cut in perfect halves to the left and right on a windows 8, but on my android s5 it is not centered?
http://danny4help.com/

```
#grad4_left img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#grad4_right {
    z-index: inherit;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #F1EEF7;
    top: 705px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #4A4A4A;
}

.grad#grad4_left {
    z-index: inherit;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 705px;
    right: 50%;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: All your divs are absolutely positioned. This takes them out of the document flow. The `body` element has no height. I wouldn't build a layout solely with absolutely positioned elements. First, because it's most likely unnecessary. Second, because of the added complexity.

Comment: But assuming you want to go that route, at a minimum I would add `body { min-height: 100vh; position: relative; }`. This will make the `body` element at least as tall as the viewport, and set the boundaries for the abspos divs.

Comment: @Michael_B I added your changes - a lot cleaner to boot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several `divs` that have fixed widths in pixels, both above and below the incorrectly centered `divs`. These `divs` are wider than the body, so the viewport automatically expands to show the full width of those elements, making it seem as though your `divs` are incorrectly centered. Simply replace the pixel units of the `width` of the too wide `divs` with either percents of viewport units and you'll be good to go (e.g., `.grad` has a width of `1280px`. Change that to `100vw`). For a quick and dirty fix, add this block to the top:

```
* {
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
```

**EDIT:** Some other answers are advising you not to use absolute positioning in responsive layouts. Using `position: absolute` is actually OK as long as you are using relative units (e.g., `%`, `em`, `vw`) and not fixed units (e.g., `px`, `in`, `pt`).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's already centered in mobile. The reason why you see it's not aligned center is because you have set your grid `div` to `width: 1280px` while the body element is only `100%`. Also as @Michael_B mentioned, besides having no `height`, it can't get the `width` of your elements inside your body element. I would advise you to not build a layout solely with `position: absolute` elements, because it will be better for responsive layouts, and I assume that you are targeting mobile.

Anyway, below are the few fixes I can suggest to you.

`html, body` add `width 100%`

`.grad` remove `width`

`.grad1` remove `height`

`.grad#grad1 img` add `max-width to 100%`, add `display: block`

`#shade` remove `position: absolute`, remove `width`

`#grad1.grad #scrolling_text` change to `width 100%`

`#block_text` remove `width`

`#nested_skills` change to `font-size: 16px` so that your `grad3 div` can take the width of your text

`.grad#grad4_right` add `overflow-y: scroll`. If you do not want to have the scrollbar then set `height: auto` but it will be a different `height` than the image on the left. Also it will not show the left margin on the left div as well as the right margin on the right div because you are using absolute.

`.grad#grad5`: you have to adjust the font size for this yourself

`.grad#grad6` add `left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto`

`.grad#grad7` add `display: block`

This should be good.